# Chrome Dev Tools and Device Mode resolution

Tags: responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently developing website and trying to make it responsive. For tests I'm using Chrome Dev Tools Device Mode, where you can set resolution of any device.

The problem is that if you choose e.g. 1920x1080 px and use media queries to style it properly for that resolution it won't fit for user browser since user will have to browse it in full screen mode.

Is there any way to set device resolution to match given resolution browser height and width or are there any good practices of styling in such a way?

Any hints welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use media queries for precise resolutions. In general, it is better to use one or some `max-width` and `min-width` conditions.

One good way is to define media queries for large, medium, small screens. You can check how bootstrap does this for example, with the corresponding breakpoints. [Bootstrap breakpoints](https://bootstrapcreative.com/bootstrap-4-media-queries/)

For my websites, I start coding for desktop, and then try to reduce the window width until I see that the UI is not good for mobile. Then I take the width and create a breakpoint with it.